# LTREE ancestor query in Postgres not working as expected

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, ltree

I have a table with an `LTREE` column, and the data is somewhat as described below.

```
ID  Label  Path
1.  ABC.   1
2.  DEF.   1.2
26. GHI.   1.2.26
```

Let's suppose I want to find **all** the ancestors of the node labelled `GHI`. The query I'm using is

```
SELECT *
    FROM
        my_table as tbl
    WHERE
        tbl.path @> (
            SELECT
                path 
            FROM
                my_table 
            WHERE
                id=26
        )
```

However, this returns only the last row, whereas I want all the three rows. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of a newcomer to Ltree as well, but I think I could help you out!

Your setup should match the GIST index for the Ltree.
See the `F.21.3` part of the official documentation. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html

I believe that without it, the operator is unable to properly figure out what you want. Besides that the query seems correct. I ran the same code on my local environment (although I use the latest version of Postgres) which worked.

Answer (score 0):

To find the all descendants for the given path use the <@ operator

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table as tbl
WHERE path <@ '1.12.26'
```

For more info https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#LTREE-OP-TABLE